# wait_event_timeout exits on timeout with condition set

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, multiprocessing

I have this piece of code in my linux kernel module:

```
spin_lock_irqsave(&ofn_lock, ofn_flag);
<several instructions>
ack_type = 1;
wake_up = 1;
spin_unlock_irqrestore(&ofn_lock, ofn_flag);
if (wake_up)
  wake_up(&wait_q);
```

And the sleeper does this:

```
#define TIMEOUT                 250

wait_event_timeout(wait_q, ack_type != 0, msecs_to_jiffies(TIMEOUT));
if (ack_type == 1) 
    retValue = OK;
else  
    retValue = TIMEOUT;
```

This code is runing on a ARM SMP with 4 cores.

Most of the time the code works correctly, but from time to time the wait exits on timeout, even though all the time ack_type is set to 1(I have a print in the waker that prints the value, and it's 1 all the time, I also have a print in the sleeper and sometimes the value is 0).

My feeling is that the problem is related to lack of memory barriers(I know that spinlocks and wake_up and wait_event all use memory barriers, so that's why I assumed that I don't need to explicitly use a memory barrier), but I'm not sure if this is actually the problem.

Does anybody know what could be the problem here?

Comment: What sets wake_up = 0?  Can it get in after 'spin_unlock_irqrestore' but before 'if (ack_type == 1)'?

Comment: wake_up is set to zero at the start of the function, it is set only in the critical section. So in the code I posted I don't need any additional memory barriers?